# Text scroll inside WPF datagrid cell in template column

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, expression-blend, wpftoolkit

My text is too long in the template column, so I am trimming the text and it ends with dots. I am showing the full text in tooltip. 
But how i can do this when a mouse is scrolled over a cell with longer text, the text should scroll from right to left. I am using WPF, and WPF toolkit `DataGrid`

Comment: Is the text in a TextBlock or a TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm reading the question wrong, but is it an instance where you could make a cell datatemplate that wraps a scrollviewer around your text and just set the scrollbar visibilities to auto?